# Is the Raspberry Pi vulnerable to the KRACKs on WPA2 networks?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, update, security

I have an updated RPI Zero W running Stretch.

The [research is stating](https://www.krackattacks.com/#details-android) that wpa_supplicant is vulnerable on all Linux machines. According to Debian patches [are rolled out](http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2017/Oct/25):

```
For the oldstable distribution (jessie), these problems have been fixed
in version 2.3-1+deb8u5.

For the stable distribution (stretch), these problems have been fixed in
version 2:2.4-1+deb9u1.

For the testing distribution (buster), these problems have been fixed
in version 2:2.4-1.1.

For the unstable distribution (sid), these problems have been fixed in
version 2:2.4-1.1.
```

My RPI is running `wpasupplicant version 2:2.4-1`:

```
apt search wpasupplicant

wpasupplicant/stable,now 2:2.4-1 armhf [installed]
  client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
```

Does that mean that Raspberry Pi's are already patched for this Crack attack?

Answer (score 15):

**Yes**, your Pis are vulnerable until the [patched versions of the Debian packages](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-13086) are available for Raspbian.

---

***Edit**: The patched versions are now [available for Raspbian](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/w/wpa/).*

Comment: **The OP is running `2:2.4-1` (vulnerable) not `2:2.4-1.1` (fixed), so the answer to his question if the Pi's are already patched is _NO_.** (Yes, it's confusing that the OP asks opposing questions in the title and the body, but this answer really needs to be very clear about this)

Answer (score 4):

**No**, (but yes it was) a fully updated Raspberry Pi (Zero) with Stretch is no longer vulnerable.

Updates were made available this early morning.

Just run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

And you're safe.

```
apt search wpasupplicant

wpasupplicant/stable,now 2:2.4-1+deb9u1 armhf [installed]
  client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes these issues almost certainly affect raspbian and the patches are not yet in the public raspbian repos.

<s>Unfortunately some things are snarled up infrastructure wise which has prevented any updates to the public raspbian repo for the last couple of days. I am trying to unsnarl stuff and get the updates out now.</s>

---

Update (20171002 01:38):

The fixes for raspbian Jessie and Stretch should now be in the public raspbian repo.

The fix for raspbian buster should follow in a few hours.

I do not know if/when there will be a fix for wheezy.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is, just after I did an update, pi zero w, raspbian jessie:

wpasupplicant/oldstable,now **2.3-1+deb8u4** armhf [installed]

I think not yet patched.